# AngularJS style position according to database value

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to style the elements in my page using the x and y position values that I'm getting from database.

Here I'm using the following code to generate divs using ng-repeat:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 areaContainer">
<div class="borderOne" ng-repeat="area in mizTableList.area" ng-style="position: relative;">{{area.no}} X:{{area.x}} Y:{{area.y}}</div>
</div>
```

Here is a sample list of database values I'm getting in the list variable:

```
[
{"ID":655412,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"100","y":"70","no":"9","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655411,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"10","y":"130","no":"8","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655410,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"660","y":"530","no":"4","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655409,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"530","y":"460","no":"3","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655408,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"530","y":"400","no":"2","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655406,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"710","y":"740","no":"24","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655405,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"430","y":"740","no":"22","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655423,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"570","y":"740","no":"23","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655426,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"10","y":"190","no":"7","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655424,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"850","y":"740","no":"25","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655422,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"150","y":"740","no":"20","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655414,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"150","y":"130","no":"12","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655417,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"450","y":"130","no":"15","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655416,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"450","y":"190","no":"14","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655413,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"10","y":"10","no":"10","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655418,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"790","y":"530","no":"5","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655419,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"970","y":"610","no":"6","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655415,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"150","y":"70","no":"13","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655407,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"650","y":"340","no":"1","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655421,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"450","y":"70","no":"16","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655420,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"150","y":"190","no":"11","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655402,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"450","y":"10","no":"17","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655403,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"310","y":"10","no":"18","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655401,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"10","y":"740","no":"19","isDeleted":"0"},
{"ID":655404,"user":null,"area":"1","x":"290","y":"740","no":"21","isDeleted":"0"}
]
```

What I want is to style those elements according to the position in variables.

I tried using ng-style, but it gives me error.
Please, suggest solutions.

### Update: issue resolved

The solution was quite simple, but I was making some mistakes in the code. The first one was I was using [] bracket notation to apply x and y for left and top values. As it turns out, angular does not play well with [] in style.
Also I was using ng-style for applying styles. Instead I had to use style attribute which works correctly.

Here is the updated working solution:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 areaContainer">
<div class="borderOne" ng-repeat="area in mizTableList.area" style="position: relative;left: {{area.x}}px; top: {{area.y}}px">{{area.no}} X:{{area.x}} Y:{{area.y}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create sub div for styling elements use ng-class

```
<div ng-repeat="area in mizTableList.area" style="position: relative;"><div class="borderOne" ng-class="condition">{{area.no}} X:{{area.x}} Y:{{area.y}}</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But it didn't work as expected. The inner div element made it to fall on the next line, and position values were not applying for left and top position values. Please check the updated solution in the question.